# Filesystem database model and a web frontend as file manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, filesystems

I'm looking for an already working solution to build some sort of filesystem on DB and a web application as file manager. Actually it doesn't seem hard, written on paper. I'm talking about a small set of tables to store a typical filesystem structure -file, folder, ownership and so on- and a web frontend for user interaction. I'd like it to eventually have sign on, to handle privileges on resources and access concurrency.

My preferred platform would be Asp.net and Sql Server.

Does anyone know about something already available on web? like an open source package? a commercial product? even just a live working scenario on the internet?

Comment: Looking to re-implement SharePoint: ASP.Net + SQL server?... Check it out first (there are [trial VHDs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417)), there were even explanations of database structures on MSDN at some point.

Comment: Thank you really much for your comment. I already had the chance to put myself in front of sharepoint workspaces but if I'm not mistaken the folder structures relied on active directory. Isn't it just a web file manager for real folders? you talk about database structures and that seems interesting. At this point I don't really think I will never work on such a project but it would be interesting to know. I guess I will check your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: SharePoint stores all data in DB and folders' structure ("document libraries" and folders inside them) does not depend on any disk file layout nor AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must confess I'm curious why you would want this. If need a filesystem, use the filesystem? If you need it remotely, set up an FTP-site? It's fast, easy and secure with freeware products like FileZilla Server.

But to your answer. The main difficulty I see here is hierarchical data. The main advantage of a relational database is well.. relations. And you don't really need that for this. Therefore I would consider a document database for this. RavenDB would probably be a good fit for you since I believe it explicitly has blob-storage capabilities. Its advantage is that it supports hierarchical data out of the box.

Since it's json based it is also a good fit for a web-api and won't require you to use a heavyweight ORM with an Entity model etc etc.

Comment: yes you are making a good point but an ftp server is based on an underlying real filesystem and that's something I need to avoid. Why? because a filesystem is not distributed and doesn't scale. Ok you may argue and say why not building a distributed filesystem? why not rely on a SAN with raid solutions or just scale on GRID? well I don't know...anyway it seems fair to consider a simple DBMS solution to start from, don't you think? I don't know RavenDB and thank you for pointing out. I will check. Anyway I'd still like to know if there's something more specific just out of curiosity. +1

Comment: I see. That sheds some significant light on your motivation :) Truly I'm not sure if RavenDb is good at scaling. Would a web-farm be an option? I'm thinking using the file storage on Windows Azure.. Should scale great.. In any case, with that scalability requirement my answer won't hold the solution for you. I don't know of any such product, but I agree with you it should be feasible to roll this on your own using wcf (for intranet) or asp.net (for internet) and Sql Server for storage. Hierarchy is a hurdle, but not THAT bad.

Comment: I want to be honest, you have been really dedicated on your answers and I appreciate it. Actually I asked the question starting from a wrong point and completely didn't consider many other easy possibilities. It helped me looking further and maybe consider new compromises. Actually I don't need at all such a big scalability and it was just an idea to abstract a concept and make it true without forcing the specific platform. At this point I can't see anymore the reason why a DB solution would really help me :) Thank you for helping me understanding this point.